# group by average on a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects where object looks like below

```
public class Sample
{
    public DateTime _dt;
    public decimal _d;
    public decimal_value;
}
```

I want a list grouped by year and month of a date and _d values with _value averaged.

So if for month Jan, list has

```
one set of 31 values with _d =1, 
one set of 31 values with _d =5
```

result list of Sample will have two values

```
1/1/2016 ,_d = 1 and average of _value
1/1/2016 ,_d = 5 and average of _value
```

Comment: Edited to public. Trying to figure out a linq way rather than running a loop and querying rest of the days available for month/year based on first instance from list.

Answer (score 0):

Initially we have to redefine the `Sample` class.

```
public class Sample
{
    public DateTime _dt   { get; set; }
    public decimal _d     { get; set; }
    public decimal _value { get; set; }
}
```

If we have a list of `Sample` objects that is called `samples`, then something like this does that you want:

```
var results = samples.GroupBy(sample => { Year = _dt.Year, Month = _dt.Month DValue = _d})
                     .Select(gr => new {
                         Year = gr.Key.Year,
                         Month = gr.Key.Month,
                         DValue = gr.Key.DValue,
                         AverageValue = gr.Select(item => item.Value).Average()
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
var results = samples
    .GroupBy(g => new { 
        Year = g._dt.Year, 
        Month = g._dt.Month, 
        _d = g._d })
    .Select(s => new { 
        Year = s.Key.Year, 
        Month = s.Key.Month, 
        _d = s.Key._d, 
        Avg = s.Average(a => a._value) });
```

For what it's worth, I'd revise your property naming conventions for style and name choices. Public properties should be Pascal Case, and their names should be more descriptive, especially if you're not going to supply summary metadata with your class. For example:

```
public class Sample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the sample's date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the sample's index
    /// </summary>
    public decimal Index
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the sample's value
    /// </summary>
    public decimal Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I've transformed the names "_dt", "_d" and "_value" to "Date", "Index" and "Value", respectively.

The style underscore with Camel Case (e.g. "_descriptivePropertyName") is typically reserved for private fields within a class, among other situations.